# I made a project in C++ CLI, But I can decompile it using a C# Decompiler

Tags: c++-cli

Is there any way, I can prevent my c++ cli project from being decompiled if someone uses a C# decompiler, because I tried to decompile the .exe i made in ILSpy and it showed my whole code, so is there any way I can prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: The point of C++/CLI is to interop with native code, producing a mixed-mode assembly.  Some of it managed and some of it native.  The native code cannot be easily decompiled back to source.  But very easy to get that wrong by compiling too much of it with /clr in effect.  It works too well, capable of compiling any C++03 compliant native C++ to MSIL.  Putting it in a static link library is a good way to avoid making the mistake.  The managed part of it can be obfuscated with any decent obfuscator.  Do ask the vendor if they support mixed-mode assemblies when you shop.

Answer (score 1):

as ancient as this thread is, I ran across it with the same question, and a newish answer. Can't specify the minimum version for this one, but

```
[module:System::Runtime::CompilerServices::SuppressIldasmAttribute];
```

on top of each .cpp module did the trick for me:

[image]

I didn't investigate much further, yet.
Another useful thing is to add

```
#pragma unmanaged
```

to each .cpp that does not contain .net code.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- Use a .NET obfuscator.

Or

- Only use C++CLI for the boundaries of your app which require to Interact with .NET. And implement your logic in a native C++ library.